# C#, if there several same character in string, how replace character in specific index in string

Tags: c#

i want to replace string like as below

00:00:01:000 > 00:00:01.000

i tried to use string.replace but it changed all of ":" to "." like as below

00:00:01:000 > 00.00.01.000

```
        a = "00:00:01:100";
        textBox2.Text=a.Replace(':', '.');
```

how can i replace only last ":" to "." ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your input string always in the exact same format?

Answer (score 0):

We can find the last index of the character using the `LastIndexOf` method, and if it's greater than `-1`, we can get the substrings around the string we found and insert our replacement string between them:

```
var a = "00:00:01:100";
var find = ":";
var replace = ".";

var lastIndex = a.LastIndexOf(find);

var result = lastIndex == -1 
    ? a
    : string.Concat(a.Substring(0, lastIndex), replace, a.Substring(lastIndex + 1));

// result = "00:00:01.100"
```